# How to show $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{\alpha}}dx <\infty$ if and only if $\alpha > n$

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to show $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{\alpha}}dx <\infty$ if and only if $\alpha > n$. So I started from polar coordinates which gave me $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^{\alpha}}dr$ but don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick is to separate the integral as follows: $$\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^\alpha}dr=\int_0^{1}\dfrac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^\alpha}dr+\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^\alpha}dr$$, and study the convergence of the latter integral only as the former is well-defined and finite.

When $\alpha>n,$ use the upper bound $\dfrac{1}{(1+r)^\alpha}< \dfrac{1}{(1+r)^n}.$ As for the divergence when $\alpha\leq n$, use the lower bound $\dfrac{1}{(1+r)^\alpha}\geq\dfrac{1}{r^\alpha}.$

It is a good exercise to fill in the details of the above hint.

Comment: +1 All the hints are there, essentially the answer is there, but there's still enough missing to make it into an exercise.